# Data exploration JSON nested data in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How can I get my JSON data into a reasonable data frame? I have a deeply nested file which I aim to get into a large data frame. All is [described](https://github.com/simongraham/dataExplore/blob/master/kaido_data.ipynb) in the Github repository below:

http://www.github.com/simongraham/dataExplore.git

Comment: Please don't link to an external resource with large data files.  Instead, include a representative *sample* of your data in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nested jsons, you will need to walk through the levels, extracting needed segments. For the nutrition segment of the larger json, consider iterating through every `nutritionPortions` level and each time running the pandas normalization and concatenating to final dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('/Users/simongraham/Desktop/Kaido/Data/kaidoData.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# INITIALIZE DF
nutrition = pd.DataFrame()

# ITERATIVELY CONCATENATE
for item in data[0]["nutritionPortions"]:    
    if 'ftEnergyKcal' in item.keys():      # MISSING IN 3 OF 53 LEVELS
        temp = (pd.io
            .json
            .json_normalize(item, 'nutritionNutrients',
                ['vcNutritionId','vcUserId','vcPortionId','vcPortionName','vcPortionSize',
                 'ftEnergyKcal', 'vcPortionUnit','dtConsumedDate'])
            )
        nutrition = pd.concat([nutrition, temp])

nutrition.head()
```

Output

```
   ftValue  nPercentRI    vcNutrient                  vcNutritionPortionId  \
0     0.00         0.0       alcohol  c993ac30-ecb4-4154-a2ea-d51dbb293f66   
1     0.00         0.0          bcfa  c993ac30-ecb4-4154-a2ea-d51dbb293f66   
2     7.80         6.0        biotin  c993ac30-ecb4-4154-a2ea-d51dbb293f66   
3    49.40         2.0       calcium  c993ac30-ecb4-4154-a2ea-d51dbb293f66   
4     1.82         0.0  carbohydrate  c993ac30-ecb4-4154-a2ea-d51dbb293f66   

  vcTrafficLight vcUnit       dtConsumedDate  \
0                     g  2016-04-12T00:00:00   
1                     g  2016-04-12T00:00:00   
2                   Âµg  2016-04-12T00:00:00   
3                    mg  2016-04-12T00:00:00   
4                     g  2016-04-12T00:00:00   

                          vcNutritionId  ftEnergyKcal  \
0  070b97a4-d562-427d-94a8-1de1481df5d1          18.2   
1  070b97a4-d562-427d-94a8-1de1481df5d1          18.2   
2  070b97a4-d562-427d-94a8-1de1481df5d1          18.2   
3  070b97a4-d562-427d-94a8-1de1481df5d1          18.2   
4  070b97a4-d562-427d-94a8-1de1481df5d1          18.2   

                               vcUserId vcPortionName vcPortionSize  \
0  fe585e3d-2863-46fe-a41f-290bf58ad169         1 mug           260   
1  fe585e3d-2863-46fe-a41f-290bf58ad169         1 mug           260   
2  fe585e3d-2863-46fe-a41f-290bf58ad169         1 mug           260   
3  fe585e3d-2863-46fe-a41f-290bf58ad169         1 mug           260   
4  fe585e3d-2863-46fe-a41f-290bf58ad169         1 mug           260   

  vcPortionId vcPortionUnit  
0           2            ml  
1           2            ml  
2           2            ml  
3           2            ml  
4           2            ml
```

Comment: Thank you @parfait that works very smoothly. Now, I can individually parse each column in to a data frame. Is it good procedure to do this and then to concatenate each data frame side by side? Or would it be best to do this all in one go if at all possible?

Comment: Great to hear! Concatenate stacks each dataframe not merges side by side. That normalized procedure takes one distinct set and not all. Had you not used `temp` only the very last `nutritionPortions` would be retained as loop keeps replacing the `nutrition` df.